# element (sporadically) fails to receive click event in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom-events

I'm having a strange issue where a click event on a button doesn’t get triggered in React. The function passed to the button onClick handler (sporadically) wouldn't run on click, so I added this event listener to the body so I could log the event object:

```
document.body.addEventListener('click', (e: any) => {
  console.log('test, e: ', e)
})
```

I could see that, when the button's onClick callback is run, the event object's `path` property looks like this:

[image]

The element `button.Buttonstyles__ButtonWrapper...` is the event target, the element that triggers the click event, which bubbles up until it reaches the Window.

But when it fails to run, the event object's `path` property looks like this:

[image]

It's as if the button didn't "receive" the click event. It should have been the event target. Instead, some parent element was the target - in this case, `div.sc-bdvvaa.bmpHsj`, but sometimes it was some other parent element higher up.

This happens (seemingly) sporadically (most times it works).

Any ideas?

Comment: can you share a codesandbox which reproduces the behaviour?

Comment: I'm having a similar issue. Did you ever get this resolved?